# Uploading docx files programmatically corrupt?

Tags: document-library, file-upload, word

Does anyone know why my programmatically uploaded Docx files arrive corrupted? I've seen more messages of this problem all over the internet without a solution.

Would it be possible for someone to post some code that would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about other examples but this one works for me (using application page)

Application page markup contains:

```
<input type="file" id="InputFile" runat="server" class="ms-fileinput" />
```

Code behind (eg. on button click):

```
var fStream = InputFile.PostedFile.InputStream;
var fileName = InputFile.PostedFile.FileName;
var contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
fStream.Close();
var list = List.GetList([TARGET LIBRARY URL HERE]);
var destinationFolder = list.RootFolder;
var strDestUrl = destinationFolder.Url + "/" + fileName;
var file = destinationFolder.Files.Add(strDestUrl, contents, true);
```

However I had experienced some corrupt file uploads in past (office docs) but only when I tried to include metadata while adding file (and not always). To avoid this I am setting all additional field values after file is added.

```
file.Item["[FIELD ITERNAL NAME"] = "[DATA]";
file.Item.SystemUpdate(false);
```

Note: I am using `SystemUpdate` to avoid new version.